# Update Shiny plot with partial progress

Tags: shiny

Is it possible to have shiny update a plot with additional data as a long running function progresses? E.g. if I am running a simulation, can new runs be added to the overall results incrementally and the plot updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your simulation as a different R process (i.e. not within Shiny). Then you can for example write the results periodically to a file, and use `reactiveFileReader` to detect change and update your plot.

Comment: Is that really the only way? I can see how it would work, but makes deploying via shinyapps.io impossible.

Comment: Yes it wouldn't work on shinyapps.io. You can probably try setup your own Shiny Server. For updating plot, that's pretty much the only way. If you only need to update some text, you can use Javascript.